# Jacobian of non-linear ODE in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I'm calculating the `jacobian` for a two-body problem, which is defined like so
[image: two-body problem]

I have set up my system of equations as follows

```
syms y1(t) y2(t) y3(t) y4(t)

r = sqrt(y1^2 + y2^2)
y3 = diff(y1)
y4 = diff(y2)
yd = [y3; y4; -y1/r^3; -y2/r^3]

jacobian(yd, [y1 y2 y3 y4])
```

However, when I run the `jacobian` function I get the following error

> The second argument must be a vector of variables.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I have also tried parametrizing `y` for t `y(t)` to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message suggests that *the second argument must be a vector of variables*, whereas in your case it is: `[y1, y2, 1, 1]`.

Also there is no need to initialize them as `symfun` class i.e. `y1(t)`, `y2(t)`, `y3(t)` and `y4(t)`, you can define them as `sym` class instead i.e. `y1`, `y2`, `y3` and `y4`

So, by initializing them as `sym` and removing the lines where you make `y3` and `y4` equal to `1`, i.e.

```
syms y1 y2 y3 y4
r = sqrt(y1^2 + y2^2);
yd = [y3; y4; -y1/r^3; -y2/r^3];
jacobian(yd, [y1 y2 y3 y4])
```

you will get this output:

```
[                                                    0,                                                    0, 1, 0]
[                                                    0,                                                    0, 0, 1]
[ (3*y1^2)/(y1^2 + y2^2)^(5/2) - 1/(y1^2 + y2^2)^(3/2),                        (3*y1*y2)/(y1^2 + y2^2)^(5/2), 0, 0]
[                        (3*y1*y2)/(y1^2 + y2^2)^(5/2), (3*y2^2)/(y1^2 + y2^2)^(5/2) - 1/(y1^2 + y2^2)^(3/2), 0, 0]
```

Comment: Specifically, `symfun` objects are not symbolic variables, but symbolic functions.